# How can I retrieve long response from mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring mvc + mongodb application, I have 400k documents. if I need to return 300k documents when a query is made, how can I do that?

Following is the stack trace,

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1634887426

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1634887426

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1634887426
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1634887426
    com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:49)
    com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:141)
    com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:135)
    com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:164)
    com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:135)
    com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:292)
    com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:271)
    com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
    com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:458)
    com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
    com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1803)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1628)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1611)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:535)
    com.AnnaUnivResults.www.service.ResultService.getStudentList(ResultService.java:38)
    com.AnnaUnivResults.www.service.ResultService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1f19973d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    com.AnnaUnivResults.www.service.ResultService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9296292.getStudentList(<generated>)
    com.AnnaUnivResults.www.controller.ResultController.searchStudentByCollOrDept(ResultController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

I guess the above stack trace is because the documents returned is very large. How can I manage this? I changed tomcat server config as 4096M. But I still have problem.

Answer (score 2):

The math first: you are trying to load more than 1.5GB in a single query. That will take a while and except for *very* rare use cases is showing - sorry - bad application design.

Don't think of how to deal with that from the database side. You should refactor your code.

There are two common scenarios for loading a lot of documents.

### Scenario 1: Calculations over the result set

Sometimes you want to do calculations over a large part of your result set. Let's say you want to find out how much turnover all customers from EMEA generated so far and your order documents look like this (simplified for the sake of this example):

```
{
 _id:<...>,
 customerId:<...>,
 deliveryAdress: {<...>},
 region: "EMEA",
 items:[{<...>},{<...>},...],
 total:12345.78
}
```

Now, what you could do to a certain extend is to load all the orders from the EMEA region with the equivalent of

```
db.orders.find({region:"EMEA"})
// the repository method would be something like
// findByRegion(String region)
```

and iterate over the result set, building a sum of `total`. This approach has several problems. First of all, even when doing it in this way, you load *a lot* of data you don't need (`items`,`deliveryAddress`). So the first way to reduce the amount of data returned by MongoDB is to use projection:

```
db.orders.find({region:"EMEA"},{_id:0,total:1})
// as of now, you would have to create a custom method
// and a custom repository implementation
// See "Further Reading"
```

which will give you a lot of documents only containing the total of all orders from EMEA, vastly reducing the size returned from the database. As far as I know, this can't be done using spring-data's dynamic finders (repositories) automagically.

But this approach still has the drawback that it doesn't scale too well, since there might be a point in time where you have more orders from EMEA than you can load in a single transaction. You could use a server side cursor and an iterator (see scenario 2 for details), but this still is a bit awkward.

A far better approach would be to let MongoDB do the calculations. For this, you would use MongoDB's aggregation framework. As for the example, the query would look like

```
db.orders.aggregate([{$match:{region:"EMEA"}},{$group:{_id:"$region",totalTurnover:{$sum:"$total"} } })
```

which would return a single document looking like

```
{_id:"EMEA",totalTurnover:<very large Sum>}
```

The advantage is obvious: you keep the load of your application, you don't need to load all the data, drastically improving the performance. And it is scalable.

### Scenario 2: You **really** need a lot of the document's

Even when you really need a lot of the documents, loading them all in one huge result set is bad practise, as that approach isn't scalable, as you found out. A better approach would be to request parts of the result set. For this you use server side cursors.

With spring-data-mongodb you would use PagingAndSortingRepository instead of a CrudRepository or any other. Since PagingAndSortingRepository is an extension of CrudRepository, migration should be quite easy. The advantage is that you only request a part of the result set at a given point in time, which makes your query scalable at the cost of manually iterating over it.

### Further reading

- [Customization of spring-data-mongodb repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.standalone)
- [Aggregation framework support in spring-data-mongodb](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation)
- [PagingAndSortingRepository in "Core Concepts" of the spring-data-mongodb docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)